# How do live CDs detect and run with a different file system?

Tags: linux

If I use a fedora live CD, how is able to detect the file system (NTFS) used by my regular windows system?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Live CD basically has the drivers required to read NTFS. This is not any different from an installed OS reading NTFS.

Comment: thanks. so theoretically, can a fedora os access the file system of a windows os even if they live on different partitions?

Comment: @most kernels in distributions now adays have native NTFS read/write support.

Comment: @OckhamsRazor Yes, as long as Fedora supports NTFS

Answer (score 1):

When booting to the Ubuntu LiveCD you will be using Unity, so this is what I am going to assume.

When you are finished booting, you click on the folder in the top left and on the left side of the new window you should see your additional HDD/partitions. Clicking on them will mount them and tada, accessible.

Comment: This is good to know, but the question is about Live CDs in general.

Comment: @iglvzx the problem is that different Live CDs use different GUIs. Even still different distributions have different mounting scripts. The only blanket statement that you can kind of safely make is, they will have a folder application, open it, lokate your drive somewhere in the interface, then click on it and it should mount the drive/partition and present it to you.